# A loop inside realm.write() or the other way around?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using the ES2015 class schema model:

```
class Person {
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

Person.schema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string'
  }
};
```

Suppose I have a long list of people, and each person item will be updated in a loop. I find that in debug mode, having the write block inside the loop is faster than the loop inside a write block.

Faster:

```
componentDidMount(){
   realmWorker.addListener(()=>{
      console.log('from search screen');
   })
}

onClick=()=>{
   let persons = realm.objects('person');
   persons.forEach(person=>{
       realm.write(()=>{
          person.age++;
          // More complicated updates.
       })
   }) 
}
```

Slower:

```
realm.write(()=>{

  let persons = realm.objects('person');
  persons.forEach(person=>{
      person.age++;
      // More complicated updates.
  }) 

})
```

But I read that the document prefers having as few write transcations as possible:

```
Note that write transactions have a non-negligible overhead; you should try to minimize the number of write blocks within your code.
```

So should I put the entire loop inside the write block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A write transaction is atomic that is, and it is all or nothing. That implies that the changes done in a transaction should be a logical change set. If you change two objects and you need some kind of consistency across those two objects, the changes should be done in one transaction. If the changes are independent, changes can (and probably should) be done in two transactions.

The above is the theory :-) What we write in the documentation is that transactions are expensive. The reason is that transactions have to acquire locks and changes have to be written to the storage.

When you are debugging a RN app, the changes are still written to storage but they are also communicated to your debugger. This is a slow process - see for example https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/491. My best guess is that many small transactions are slow when debugging due to the app/debugger communication overhead. In the real-life scenario (the user using your app - without a debugger), the write transaction outside the loop will be faster.